# How to make a server use a amount of ram specified from a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jvm, settings

Okay so I need help with this so I have a batch file for running a server but I want a way were the user can just type his/her settings in a file let's just say `settings.txt` and in that file would be let's just say

```
MaxRam = (amount of ram)
```

and in the batch file it run's this code

```
java -Xms(amount of ram from settings.txt file)G -Xmx(amount of ram from settings.txt file)G -jar server.jar -o true nogui
```

so then all the user has to do is change the amount of ram from the `settings.txt` file. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

in fact, that's quite easy:

```
REM write a value to the file:
> settings.txt echo MaxRam=50000
REM read value(s) from the file:
for /f "delims=" %%a in (settings.txt) do set %%a
java -Xms%MaxRam%G -Xmx%MaxRam%G -jar server.jar -o true nogui
```

You can also have more than one setting in the file, for example:

```
> settings.txt echo MaxRam=50000
>>settings.txt echo Setting=true
>>settings.txt echo Gui=nogui

for /f "delims=" %%a in (settings.txt) do set %%a
java -Xms%MaxRam%G -Xmx%MaxRam%G -jar server.jar -o %Setting% %Gui%
```

(of course in your program you won't write to the file...)

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work your just making a var MaxRam=50000
i want MaxRam=(setting's from settings.txt file)

Comment: @CalebTharratt I said `(of course in your program you won't write to the file...)`. Skip the part that writes `settings.txt`